# Ricci tensor of Lie group is independent of the bi-invariant metric

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group endowed with a bi-invariant metric $Q$. Then
$$\mathrm{Ric}(X,Y)=\mathrm{tr\ }\frac{1}{4}[[X, ·],Y]=-\frac{1}{4}B(X,Y),\qquad B(X,Y):=\mathrm{tr\ }(\mathrm{ad}(X)\circ \mathrm{ad}(Y)).$$
Where $B$ is a symmetric bilinear form called Killing form of $G$.

**Claim:** Ricci tensor $\mathrm{Ric}$ of Lie group $G$ is independent of the bi-invariant metric $Q$.

Is it really this clime true? Because $B$ is defined using trace operator and trace isn't independent of metric. Isn't?

Comment: The question you are asking is this. Suppose I have an endomorphism $T$ of a vector space $V$, then is the trace of the endomorphism independent of the metric?

Comment: Or is the real question why the formula for $B(X,Y)$ holds for any biinvariant metric?